# Check the validity of npm secret access token

Tags: npm

I'm trying to validate the liveness and scope of npm access token `npm_{AlphaNumeric}` generated from https://registry.npmjs.org.

I have tried:

```
npm token list
npm whoami
npm config set //registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=npm_{alphaNumeric}
npm token list
npm logout
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.